# How to disable element in IE Browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i want to disable an animation element just in one browser (IE)
how can i work this?
or how can i Make css3 Elements Work in IE?

style =

```
  -webkit-animation: drop 8s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 0.5) infinite;  
  -moz-animation: drop 8s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 0.5) infinite;  
  -o-animation: drop 8s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 0.5) infinite;  
  animation: drop 8s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 0.5) infinite;
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable it in IE? Is it only in the old IE's or in the new ones (IE10+) too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    alert('IE'); 
    // Disable Animation
    $("#element").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

You can also target a specific version of IE like

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 8) {
    alert('IE8'); 
    // Disable Animation
} else {
    alert('Non IE8');
}
```

Edit: As the commenters say, this will not work for jQuery 1.9+. The only other option that I can think of if you're using 1.9+ is to use a plugin for browser detection. I use [CSS Browser selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) which appends browser specific information as classes to the page's html tag. From there you can make the changes.

Using [CSS Browser selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/), you can target ie to remove your element like

```
$(".ie #element").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

OR for a specific version

```
$(".ie8 #element").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Other suggestions are to use the jquery.support function. However this is an internal function, and the jquery for .support docs clearly states "specific properties may be removed when they are no longer needed internally", so I would not recommend using this.

Comment: Please don't use this code. It is deprecated and not the correct way to do it.

Comment: Reminder: jQuery.browser is no longer available in version 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case, I'd recommend using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com). When you use this, it detects what all features your browser  supports and applied relevant classes to the  element.

Then, you can use those modernizr classes to target your css classes and, for example, remove animation property from all browsers which don't support animations.